# TikZ nested foreach loop and if-then-else statement don't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I am trying to draw an annulus on a square grid which represents pixels of an image sensor. If the center of the pixel is on the annulus, i.e. between the outer and inner circles, it will be filled with green color. Otherwise, the pixel should be filled red color.

My current code (without checking the inner circle yet) is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\outerradius{5}
\def\innerradius{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm,scale=0.35,font=\small,
  lightgreenpixel/.style={green!20!white,},
  lightredpixel/.style={red!20!white,},
  ]

  \draw[help lines,thick,] (-5,-5) grid (5, 5);
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) circle [radius=5];
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) circle [radius=1];

  \foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5}
    \foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{((\x+0.5)*(\x+0.5)+(\y+0.5)+(\y+0.5)) < \outerradius*\outerradius ? int(1) : int(0)}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \fill[lightgreenpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
      \else
        \fill[lightredpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
      \fi
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown below which does not look right at all.

[image]

I have been searching how to use *if-then-else* statements withing TikZ `\foreach` loop and got a feeling that the `\pgfmathparse` command is the right one to use. However I might be on the wrong boat. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used an addition instead of a multiplication in the second term of `(\x+0.5)*(\x+0.5)+(\y+0.5)*(\y+0.5)` (your code had `(\x+0.5)*(\x+0.5)+(\y+0.5)+(\y+0.5)`). Also, the upper loop bounds needed a little adjustment, otherwise you weren't too far.

I draw the circles after the pixels so that we can see them (alternatively, you could use `opacity`).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\outerradius{5}
\def\innerradius{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  y=-1cm, scale=0.35, font=\small,
  lightgreenpixel/.style={green!20!white,},
  lightredpixel/.style={red!20!white,},
  ]

  % These can be precomputed to save time.
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\innersquared}{(\innerradius)^2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\outersquared}{(\outerradius)^2}

  \foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,4}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtwo}{(\x+0.5)^2 + (\y+0.5)^2}
      \pgfmathparse{(\rtwo < \innersquared ? 0 :
                      (\rtwo < \outersquared ? 1 : 0))}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \fill[lightgreenpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
      \else
        \fill[lightredpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
      \fi
    }

  \draw[help lines,thick,] (-5,-5) grid (5, 5);
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) circle [radius=5];
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, stupid me to use the wrong operator. Thanks also for the extra example on ```\pgfmathsetmacro``` and the nested ```x?y:z``` operator. I am going through the Mathematical engine chapter in the PGF/TikZ manual so hopefully I will understand more about the underlying principles.

Comment: You're welcome. `\pgfmathsetmacro\yourmacro{...}` is essentially a shorthand for `\pgfmathparse{...}\let\yourmacro\pgfmathresult` (actually, it does the `\pgfmathparse` inside a group and uses `\pgfmath@smuggleone` to... smuggle, indeed, the token defined with `\let` out of the group).

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of @frougon answer (+1). It differ in definition of the coloring conditions:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\def\outerradius{5}
\def\innerradius{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm,scale=0.35,font=\small,
  lightgreenpixel/.style={green!20!white,},
  lightredpixel/.style={red!20!white,},
  ]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\innerradius^2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{\outerradius^2}
  \foreach \x in {-5,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {-5,...,4}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{int((\x+0.5)^2 + (\y+0.5)^2)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult>\r
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult<\R
            \fill[lightgreenpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
        \else
            \fill[lightredpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
        \fi
    \else
       \fill[lightredpixel] (\x,\y) rectangle ++(1,1);
    \fi
    }
\draw[help lines,thick] (-5,-5) grid (5, 5);
\draw[thick] (0, 0) circle [radius=5] 
             (0, 0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result is the same as in @frougon  answer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. This is indeed another solution I would like to find as I tried to use the ```\ifnum``` command at the first place!

Comment: @Fanpeng, solution has two ˙\ifnum˙ commands in its elementary form :-)